# Interface implementation and common function

Tags: c#, java, oop, interface, abstract-class

I have the following requirement,

- There will be 2(or more) different classes to perform same kind of operation(in  different ways). Therefore I decided to create an interface. Then I implemented these 2 classes with my interface.
- Now, from another class I will be using the object of type Interface and calls functions. Everything works fine.
- Then a new requirement came to create a common functionality that applies to both classes.
- I don't want to define same function in both classes. And interface dont allows function definition.
- First I thought abstract class will be useful. Because it allows function definition and abstract functions. But abstract classes cant be instantiated and also I need to create objects with individual class types.

Sorry I cant find a simple way to define my problem. It feels like a solution that spring framework provides. But I need to know how to acheive this from a Java/C# application.

Comment: java8 interface provides methods with there body

Comment: If this "common functionality" works the same for all kinds of objects that implement that interface (and only uses members of the interface), then maybe an extension method would help. Something like `public static class ITheInterfaceExtension { public static void DoSomething(this ITheInterface item) { // do something } }`. This would *almost* be like if the interface defined the method directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you want an abstract class implementing the common functionality, but still have two concrete classes for the distinct functionality. You may or may not still want to keep the interface as well. So the options are:

```
        Interface
            ^
            |
         Abstract
          class
            ^
           / \
   Concrete   Concrete 
   class 1    class 2
```

or just

```
         Abstract
          class
            ^
           / \
   Concrete   Concrete 
   class 1    class 2
```

Code which wants to *use* these classes just uses the interface or abstract class. How you configure which concrete class to use were will depend on your exact requirements - but presumably you'd already tackled that in the earlier version.

Comment: Exactly my thoughts. But I think OP should have put more thought on whether it should be an interface or and abstract class based on the philosophy is-a and has-a.

Comment: Thanks Jon. This worked. But I was thinking it would be better if I can call this common function in abstract class from one point. Because after the implementation of interface functions I have to call this common function. Now I am calling this common function from all Concrete classes individually...

Comment: If the functionality of the method is not instance dependent then just create a static method in abstract class and call it from wherever you want.

Comment: @Vivek: I thought the point was that the common functionality was available *from* the concrete classes. I'm afraid it's quite difficult to follow your requirements.

Comment: @Jon Your second point(Abstract class) is all I need,               public void callerPoint(){  /*this function is defined in abstract class*/
        overridedMethod();  /*this function is implemented in child/concrete class*/
        commonfunction();   /*this function which is defined in abstract class will be called right after*/
    }

Answer (score 2):

A common pattern for this is:

1. Define the interface (as you've done).
2. Create an abstract class which implements the common functionality in terms of the non-common functionality.
3. Extend this abstract class to provide the non-common functionality.

A lot of JDK classes do this. For instance, the `List<T>` interface has an `AbstractList<T>` abstract class, which is extended to provide both `ArrayList<T>` and `LinkedList<T>`.

A simple (if contrived) example would be something like:

```
interface IntThingy {
    int getValue();
    int getDoubeValue();
}

abstract class AbstractIntThingy implements IntThingy {
    @Override
    public int getDoubleValue() {
        return getValue() * 2;
    }
}

class ConstantFourtyTwo extends AbstractIntThingy {
    @Override
    public int getValue() {
        return 42;
    }
}

class ConstantIntThingy extends AbstractIntThingy {
    private final int value;

    ConstantIntThingy(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Note that once Java 8 arrives, you'll be able to define methods in interfaces. These are commonly known as "defender methods." When that happens, you may not need the abstract class -- depending on whether that common functionality needs to maintain its own state (interfaces still won't be able to define instance state). But for now, the interface-abstract-concrete pattern often works well.

Comment: Thanks for notifying java8 defender methods feature

Answer (score 1):

You can try to avoid using simple interface and use strategy pattern:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

Comment: How does that helps? OP wants to have `common functionality that applies to both classes`

Comment: Every concrete strategy indeed shares the same functionality defined in strategy interface.

Answer (score 0):

Create a concrete class (or better abstract class) that implements your interface, and contains your "common functionality", Now you can extend this class (Hierarchy) with two (or more) classes.

there are many more ways of designing this requirement.
And I am not sure If mine is best either.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on to Jon Skeet's answer, you need to think as to what kind of relationship your classes have with the interface or the intended abstract class. If the relationship is between the behaviour laid out in the interface is has-a then the interface is the right choice, and if it is an is-a relationship, you can go with an abstract class.

In another scenario, you can also check if the relationship is has-a, and the new common functionality that you want to implement is an is-a relationship, then apart from option by Jon, you can use something like this:

```
           Abstract
            class
              ^
             / \
Interface            Interface
     \                /    
     Concrete   Concrete 
     class 1    class 2
```

for e.g.:

```
interface IParent{}

abstract class Parent{}

class Child1: Parent, IParent{}

class Child2: Parent, IParent{}
```

It all depends how you design your classes for future use.